# Sublime Text 2 snippet substitution RegEx: lookahead not taking accented characters

Tags: regex, macros, sublimetext2

I'm trying to do a substitution where I need to find spaces followed by a number or a letter, with or without accents, to replace them with an underscore. I currently have this (note the space in the beginning):

```
 \b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9àéèêëîïôöûü])
```

With the string `test string école test`, the replacement looks like this:

```
test_string école_test
```

I guess you got the problem, but just in case, the expected result is this:

```
test_string_école_test
```

The strangest thing is that if I just search for `[a-zA-Z0-9àéèêëîïôöûü]`, it matches every single one of the letters, so my RegEx seems just fine...

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Try dropping the `\b` - it's not essential to your query (you're already matching the space), and there unicode support is patchy in regular expressions.  It's possible the boundary detection is ASCII only.

Comment: Oh, right... Thanks a lot! It's because I was originally trying to do a negative lookahead (matching for symbols this time), but it wasn't working out, so I tried the other way around.

Comment: Kay.  Since it worked, I'm going to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `\b` - it's not essential to your query (you're already matching the space), and unicode support is patchy in regular expressions. The boundary detection is ASCII only in Sublime Text 2.